# How to Update a MySQL Table Based on SELECT MAX() from a JOINED Table

Tags: mysql, select, join, set

I have 2 MySQL Tables.

```
TableA
ID Total
01 0
02 0
03 0
...
99 0

TableB
ID Name Points Year
01 Joe  4      2013
01 Bill 2      2013
02 Sam  10     2013
02 Barb 1      2013
02 Joan 7      2013
...
15 Fred 0      2013
15 Jan  3      2013
...
```

I want to store the `MAX(Points)` value from `Table B` based on `ID` in the `Total` column in `Table A`

I have a MySQL Query that gets me the `MAX(Points)`. Rather than coding a separate `UPDATE` query while looping through the results set from my `MAX()` query, I am wondering if I can accomplish this all in one MySQL query using a Join and a `SET SELECT` of some sort.

Is this possible to consolidate the 2 queries into 1?

Here is my MAX() Query:

```
$result = mysql_query('
    SELECT id, MAX(Points)
    FROM TableB
    WHERE year = "' . date('Y') . '"
    GROUP BY id
') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    mysql_query('
        UPDATE TableA
        SET Total = "' . $row[1] . '"
        WHERE id = "' . $row[0] . '"
    ') or die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this as your SQL statement:

```
UPDATE tablea
JOIN (
    SELECT id, max(points) AS total
    FROM tableb
    WHERE year=<whatever>
    GROUP BY id
) AS sub ON tablea.id=sub.id
SET tablea.total=sub.total
```

Comment: OK. Hang on, I'll set up a test and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @nurdglaw. I like the possibility that this might work. I appreciate your coding help.

Comment: @H.Ferrence - sorry, this is proving harder than I expected. It seems I can't use `GROUP BY` with a multi-table update, and I haven't managed to make a subquery work yet. Still trying...

Comment: I was thinking I needed to `join` the 2 tables and somehow do a `SET total = SELECT`...(of some sort)

Comment: Have a try at my second attempt above - I've tested this one! :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out. That was what I was envisioning but I just didn't have the experience to piece it together. (I pseudo coded it in my head) I'll post back and let you know if my table updates properly. Thanks for helping @nurdglaw.